# How long could a Schauspielunterrichtsstunden be?

Tags: meaning, vocabulary

In Movies SE I've asked [How long after Luc Besson's "discovery" of Natalya Rudakova did the filming of Transporter 3 begin? Just a few "hours" or "lessons" later?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/116316/45856) and in the question I've tried to squeeze as much as possible out of "Schauspielunterrichtsstunden" from the German Wikipedia article [Natalya Rudakova; Leben](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natalya_Rudakova#Leben):

> Sie wuchs in Leningrad (heute Sankt Petersburg) auf und erhielt dort als Kind zunächst Zeichen- und Schauspielunterricht. Später konnte sie diesen aufgrund der schwierigen Zeiten nach dem Zusammenbruch der Sowjetunion nicht mehr besuchen. Ihre Mutter ging mit ihr jeden Sonntag ins Theater, wo sie eine Begeisterung für Schauspielerei entwickelte. Im Alter von 17 Jahren zog sie aus einer Entscheidung ihrer Mutter heraus nach New York City, wo sie später als Friseurin arbeitete.
>
> Rudakova gab in dem französisch-US-amerikanischen Actionfilm Transporter 3 ihr Filmdebüt. Dort spielt sie als Valentina Tomilenko an der Seite von Auftragsfahrer und Titelheld Frank Martin (Jason Statham) die weibliche Hauptrolle. **Sie wurde von Drehbuchautor und Produzent Luc Besson in New York beim Überqueren einer Straße entdeckt. Die Dreharbeiten zum Film begannen wenige Schauspielunterrichtsstunden später.**

Would *Schauspielunterrichtsstunden* refer only to a single lesson of a few hours, or could it also refer to a mini-course or a full course of lessons, say several weeks of several hours on several days per week?

Comment: This is a German compound that does not exist as word on its own, but is made up for this one sentence. The parts are *Schauspiel* = "drama", but more likely"acting" in this context, *Unterricht* = "lesson", *Stunden* = "hours". So whatever you can glean from the parts is what the word means. To me, the paragraph is not specific enough to answer your question. This is typical of Wikipedia style, to summarize rather than include detail that's not of general interest.

Comment: @RDBury Please do not answer in comments :)

Comment: @choXer: I was being careful not to answer the question, unless you count a comment to the effect that the question can't be answered as an answer. I didn't realize that *Unterrichtsstunde* is a standard thing though, so I stand corrected on that point.

Comment: The WP page does not give a reference for this particular claim, but it seems to be taken from the linked Cosmopolitan article https://www.cosmopolitan.com/entertainment/celebs/news/a2769/Natalya-Rudakova-interview. “A few months and a handful of acting classes later, she quit her job at a hair salon and jetted off to Europe to shoot the film.”

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An *Unterrichtsstunde* is a single lesson or session of an hour (or perhaps even shorter, e.g. 45 minutes) length. It depends on one's curriculum, how many such lessons for a specific subject one has per day and week. If you have two lessons of English every day but only one lesson of German per week, then "wenige Englischunterrichtsstunden später" might perhaps even be on the same or next day and "wenige Deutschunterrichtsstunden später" could mean several months. Of course, if you attend a drama school, it can be expected that you have *lots* of lessions on that matter, already more than "a few" on a single day. But the quoted text is certainly hyperbolic in this respect. I'd assume it to mean "several days or perhaps weeks later, but they didn't wait for her to graduate or even complete her current course"